# CiviCRM appears to block edit of WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I am newly trying to fix a website that is built using WordPress and hosted by a third provider. The site has not been maintained as best I can tell for about 5 years. My main action so far has been to upgrade to WP 5.0.3.

But when I try to edit any page in the site (having gone in through WP's back end), I get this message on an otherwise blank page: “Please select a CiviCRM front-end page type.”

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you let us know what version of CiviCRM you have?

Comment: Hm. I can't tell the version, except that the last modification of files was in September 2012. So it was probably the version that was current then or an earlier version. The hosts control panel does not reveal the CiviCRM version. And when I go into WP from the back end and look at the CRM plug in I get another error message -- maybe another clue?

Comment: The CRM error in WP is an initialization error. It starts out saying: Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -24
    [message] => DB Error: connect failed
    [mode] => 16

Comment: That message makes it pretty clear its a dB error (also says type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: connect failed" code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]"]
)

Comment: Beyond figuring out how to fix the problem, I would also like to understand why the problem would block editing of any and all pages in WP?

Comment: Aha--was able to dig deeper. CiviCRM version 4.1

Comment: That's a seriously old version of CiviCRM @DavidMinger - I'm not surprised that you're getting errors and I strongly suggest you upgrade. When/if you do, try upgrading to, say, 4.4 first, then 4.6 or 4,7, then to the latest. And always keep backups at each stage of the process. You might have to upgrade WordPress in stages too.

Comment: Thanks, Christian! I'll proceed along those lines.